# javascript FB object not ready when I call FB.Canvas.setSize in Opera

Tags: javascript, facebook, opera, facebook-javascript-sdk

In my FB app I am making a call to FB.Canvas.setSize(); to fit the page to the length of my content. This is working as intended in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and IE. It would appear, however, that Opera is calling it sooner than the rest of the browsers and is trying to resize before the FB object is ready to accept such a request. It's not throwing a JS exception so the FB object is not null but it fails to resize the page. If I put a breakpoint in before the resize is called and wait a couple seconds and then let it go through it DOES resize the page. Also, other FB functions are working (requests, feed posts, etc.). Are there any known issues with Opera and the Facebook JS SDK or any considerations I should be making for how Opera executes Javascript?

Comment: Which version of Opera do you test?

Comment: Are you calling setSize() with no parameters? It could be that the FB object is ready, but the page is not fully rendered so the size is not determined correctly. Try specifying a literal height/width and see if that makes it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to let you know, this seems like a "known" Facebook/Opera bug. You may also follow progress here: [developers.facebook.com/bugs](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/188820761219553/)

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the async way of integrating FB JS, e.g.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            resizeFacebookCanvas();
        }   
        function resizeFacebookCanvas(){
            if ( FB && FB.Canvas && FB.Canvas.setSize ){
                FB.Canvas.setSize({ 
                    width: 520, 
                    height: 900
                });
            }               
        }   

        (function() {
            var e = document.createElement('script');
            e.type = 'text/javascript';
            e.src = document.location.protocol +
            '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
            e.async = true;
            document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
        }());

</script>
```

Comment: I'm actually not, would this have an impact on this? Or is it more of a, try it and we'll find out? heh